Best way to add a switch or circuit inbetween two voltages with different names
I have two different PCBs lets call them PCB A and PCB B. In PCB A, it has two voltage sources 3V3 and 5V5. Both of these voltages are name 3V3 tool and 5V5 tool as they supply a different function of the PCB and makes it easier to turn on/off these specific voltages. At start up the voltage will be availble to the tool, but can be disabled using GPIO pins from the Microcontroller. These can be visible in the images given below.


In PCB B we have the same set up, except the availablity of a microcontroller. The voltages are active when we switch ON or inactive when we switch OFF the PCB. I wanted to know if there is a better way to draw the schematic, so that it is not shown as the below image. It doesnt not need to be turned on or off at specific intervals since it doesnt have a microcontroller. It turns Off when the voltage is removed, and viceversa.

I was thinking between two variations

Adding a MOSFET switching circuit so as to provide a necessary barrier in-between the 3V3 and 3V3tool voltage even though they turn on and off at the same time.


Adding a 0R resistor between the voltages.
The 3V3 and 3V3tool voltage along with the 5V5 and 5V5tool voltage supply different part of the PCBs and hence need to be separated.
Is there a better way to draw this or to seperate the two voltages?



Do you simply want to find a way to represent on the schematic for your PCB B that its 3.3 volt and the 5.5 volt power  rails are switched externally ? If so, just choose better names such as 3v3_switched instead of 3v3_Tool.
The relevance of the LTspice simulation with the pulsed power supply is not clear. The high side switch (the second schematic) needs some explanation. Why has it two N channel devices ?

If you can observe in the first two images, The volatge flow through the P-channel mosfet and are switched off when it receives an input from a microcontroller. here the voltage through the pchannel mosfet and hence making the 'input' and 'output' side. And can name the same voltage with different naming. I would like to do the same thing with PCB B although it doesnt have a microcontroller. Flow through a mosfet or something similar where i can clearly distinguish the two voltages
